# Search with hyphen, without and with a space

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I tokenize a hyphenated term such that I can search using the following acceptance criteria:

- with a hyphen (co-trimoxazole)
- without a hyphen (cotrimoxazole)
- with a space (co trimoxazole)

I managed to use the standard analyzer which tokenizes on hyphens both on the index side and query side which allows me to search on:

- cotrimoxazole
- co-trimoxazole

but not

- co trimoxazole

Comment: try pattern analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest usage of [combo analyzers](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/).
Here create 2 analyzer , one which tokenizes based on standard analyzer and other based on white space.

This should work fine for you.